# Where to create/manage roles and ACL/CLP permissions

Tags: parse-server

I'm working on a parse app that I'm hosting on an AWS EC2 instance. It's not clear to me from the documentation where I should create and manage Roles and set ACL and CLP permissions within the codebase. I'd also like to change CLP permissions based on a user setting (if a specific object is shared, I'd like to set read access for all, but if not, set it to only permit admin and creator read access, etc.)

In the documentation, it's clear how to do these things, but it's not clear where it should be done. When I create a Role, should that be done in code somewhere in the app (front end or back end), or should I use the parse-dashboard? Adding users to Roles should require high level permissions, so when a user signs up (is created), where do I add them to the appropriate Role relation? It seems like I can't do that on the front end.

Where do I set and change permissions on a class or specific object? Does that happen when the object is created on the front end app or should I hook into the object creation on the back end and set it there?

Thank you!

Comment: The Parse Dashboard is a very convenient way to manage User, Role, ACL, and CLP. User and Role are displayed under the Browser menu and you can manage the data that is displayed in a table format. The CLP can be managed in each class. There is a menu option to change the CLP settings in the topper right side of the class table. The ACL can be managed by row. Each row has a column for the ACL setting. The ACL is also commonly set through the API when you are creating a new object. Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. It sounds like it’s meant to be managed external to app code (via the UI or scripted otherwise), except ACL, which can be set on the front end (via API). (Repeating to make sure my understanding is correct)

Comment: You can actually also script and set CLP through the JS SDK or the REST API.

Comment: I’ve been investigating and decided to set ACL in the front end script when a class is created or updated and to add users to the appropriate role in cloud code when they are created. Curious to know if this is the “right” (most secure) way. I’m building a public-facing app.

Comment: Yes. It looks a good approach to me.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I actually moved setting the ACL to the back end as well. Now it’s impenetrable!